# Responsive swiping carousel to use with PhoneGap Build - does one exist?

Tags: html, mobile, responsive-design, carousel, phonegap-build

I have been searching and am beyond frustrated. Can anyone help?

I have tried FlexPaper, this won't swipe left to right in single page view.
I tried Fotorama but it didn't have a PhoneGap Build plugin.
MouseSwipe is just buggy.
SwipeView is not responsive.
Swipejs didn't work making my photos responsive.
FlexSlider works on my desktop but not in my iOS.

Comment: You could build one with jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Thank you for the response, @subjective-effect, can you please be more specific? Is there a jQueryMobile carousel that you know of that works after compiling with PhoneGap Build?

Comment: jQM has a swipe abilities: http://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/ I've used this to create a swipe interface for two intro screens in the past - and this works with PhoneGap Build. There is no reason you can't use it create your own carousel.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this after a bit of searching, works pretty good!

https://github.com/maaaaark/bcSwipe